# jquery enable submit button when select an option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i need to enable submit button when user select an option and this is a dynamic data. 
my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="xxx" id="member">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <select name="status">
            <option value="a">aktif</option>
            <option value="l">terkunci</option>
            <option value="b" selected="b">blokir</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="update_buyer" value="TRUE" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
        <td>
            <button role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button>&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save" disabled="disabled" value="Save">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
        <form method="post" action="xxx" id="member">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td> 
        <td>
        <select name="status">
            <option value="a" selected="a">aktif</option>
            <option value="l">terkunci</option>
            <option value="b">blokir</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="update_buyer" value="TRUE" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
        <td>
            <button role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-email="tess@email.com">Delete</button>&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save" disabled="disabled" value="Save">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
```

i try

```
$('select').change(function(){
$('.save').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

but it enable all submit button, i just want to enable which user click, not all submit button.

maybe like

```
$('select').change(function(){
$(this).parent('form').find('.save').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

but it doesn't work :( how do i do this? help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.prop()`:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('.save').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

### Note:

You have `same id for both forms` this can cause issue and `its invalid` to use this way. `ID should be unique` to elems on a single page.

Comment: EDIT: i use foreach for form ID's and it produce unique form like "member1,member2,...memberX" anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try this one -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').change(function(){
       $('.save').removeAttr('disabled');        
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('select').change(function(){
 $('.save').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

.parent method only goes up the DOM tree once, so that code will only work if the form element is the imediate parent of the select element, in this case it isnt. Use .parents() instead.

```
$('select').change(function(){
  $(this).parents('form').find('.save').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Also, note that your first select is not inside a <td>

EDIT: Other suggestions using .parent() that seem to work happen to be taking advantage of your invalid HTML (tr without table, unopened td, etc), they will not work with proper html, either remove the rows and columns and use other elements or build proper valid tables (one table per form)

Comment: i put `<table>` before `<form>` tag. i just don't write in here :) btw thanks

Comment: The resulting html is still invalid, sadly you cant put <form> between rows, the browsers will usually push the form outside the table (with no contents), meaning that if you submit, no values will be passed with the form. I suggest inspecting the code with a developer tool, to see the DOM structure the browser has built for your html.

Answer (score 0):

your second code is working , however you have invalid HTML tags.. chck it out..

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/TktAC/) is the working fiddle using your code.

```
$('select').change(function(){
  $(this).parent('form').find('.save').removeAttr('disabled');
});
-^----here
```

**note:** i could see you are missing bracket at the end of change function...(not sure if it is a typo)

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7vGaQ/1/)

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $(this).parent().children('.save').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your forms different ID names.. they are both id="member", they need to be unique. Not sure that is your error.

This worked for me even with same ID's.

```
$('#member select[name=status]').change(function(){
    $('#member input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
 })
```